# The meaning of calling a function with dictionaries

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, return

I have been very confused with the use of function and dictionaries. There is an example in the book I am using to learn python but it does not explain much why the author wrote it like that. That's why I am hoping somebody can explain to me why the script is written in this form. Here is the script:

```
def get_specials():
    monday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds', \
    'L': 'Momma\'s curry. Note: can be made spicy.',\
    'D': 'Beef brisket. Note: Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice"'}
    tuesday = {'B': 'Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed.',\
    'L': 'Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese.',
    'D': 'Meatloaf. Note: Comes with catsup on the top. Not optional.'}
    wednesday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds', \
    'L': 'Momma\'s curry. Note: can be made spicy.',\
    'D': 'Beef brisket. Note: Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice"'}
    thursday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds', \
    'L': 'Momma\'s curry. Note: can be made spicy.',\
    'D': 'Beef brisket. Note: Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice"'}
    friday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds', \
    'L': 'Momma\'s curry. Note: can be made spicy.',\
    'D': 'Beef brisket. Note: Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice"'}
    saturday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds', \
    'L': 'Momma\'s curry. Note: can be made spicy.',\
    'D': 'Beef brisket. Note: Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice"'}
    sunday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: better than it sounds', \
    'L': 'Momma\'s curry. Note: can be made spicy.',\
    'D': 'Beef brisket. Note: Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice"'}

    specials = {'M': monday, 'T': tuesday, 'W': wednesday, 'R': thursday, 'F': friday, 'St': saturday, 'Sn': sunday}
    return specials

def print_special(special):
    print "The special is: "
    print special
    print "*"*15

def get_day():
    while True:
        day = raw_input("Day (M/T/W/R/F/St/Sb): ")
        if day.upper() in ['M', 'T', 'W', 'R', 'F', 'ST', 'SN']:
            return day.upper()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid.".format(day)

def get_time():
    while True:
        time =raw_input("Time (B/L/D): ")

        if time.upper() in ['B', 'L', 'D']:
            return time.upper()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't a valid time.".format(time)

def main():
    specials = get_specials()
    print "This script will tell you the specials for any day of the week, and any time."

    while True:
        day = get_day()
        special = specials[day]

        time = get_time()
        print_special(special[time])
        another = raw_input("Do you want to check another day and time? (Y/N)")

        if another.lower() == 'n':
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My doubts are mainly in the def main() section. Could someone explain to me how this whole thing is being called? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Based on the unpythonic backslashes, I'd recommend you get a different book.

Comment: You might be interested in http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: Along with the backslashes that are completely unnecessary, the whole program looks like it was converted from some other language, or is just plain bad. Unfortunately, there are too many bad tutorials in the world.

Comment: This won't even work correctly, since `get_day()` returns an uppercase string, but this is used to access a dictionary with mixed-case keys.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions!! The learnpythonthehardway.org/book is a great suggestion. I will be learning python from that soon!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change the `get_day` function so that the prompt suggests the correct code for each day which maps to the prompt (e.g., "ST" instead of "Sb"):

```
def get_day():
    while True:
        day = raw_input("Day (M/T/W/R/F/ST/SN): ")
        if day.upper() in ['M', 'T', 'W', 'R', 'F', 'ST', 'SN']:
            return day.upper()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid.".format(day)
```

Then, change the return value of `get_specials` to match:

```
specials = {'M': monday, 'T': tuesday, 'W': wednesday, 'R': thursday, 'F': friday, 'ST': saturday, 'SN': sunday}
return specials
```

Now for the explanation:

`get_specials` retuns a dictionary of dictionaries.

`specials` is a dictionary of each day (`monday`, `tuesday`...) and each day is a dict with keys for time `['B','L','D']`

In the `main` procedure, you're prompting the user to input a day and time. The `main` procedure then returns the *item* corresponding with the day (as `special`), and from that, returns the *value* associated with the *time* key.

In the `main` procedure, this line returns the `specials`,

```
specials = get_specials()
```

If we recall from above explanation this returns a dictionary of dictionaries:

> `specials` is a dictionary of each day (`monday`, `tuesday`...) and
>   each day is a dict with keys for time `['B','L','D']`

This line then returns the second level of the `specials` returned above, so, it returns the B/L/D dictionary for the specific *day*

```
special = specials[day]
```

Since this is also a dictionary keyed by the B/L/D (time), then we can retrieve the special for a particular *time*:

```
print_special(special[time])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and help. I have one more question.
why special = specials[day] and print_special(special[time])? I don't really understand this part. why can't I put special = specials[day] and special = specials[time]?

Comment: Yeah the if __name__ ==... that specifies what to run when the module is called

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I meant was what is the difference between both of them? Can you explain to me what those two expressions mean?

Comment: Difference between both of *what*? There's only one expression there.

Comment: What is the meaning of these expression?

1) special = special[day]
2) print_special(special[time])

What is the difference between print_special(special[time]) and special = specials[time]? Why I can write special = specials[day] and not for special = specials[time].

Comment: Simply because dictionaries store a key/value pair, and to retrieve the value you must provide the unique key. You can't retrieve a key from a value, because that's not how dicts work (and because values are not necessarily unique within the dictionary).  So the reason you can't do specials[time] is because the `time` is not a key in the `specials` dictionary.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand how it works!! Thanks a lot David.